# Galera Cluster Dockerfile

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, docker, containers, galera

I'm trying to create a galera docker image based on this dockerfile file from this link 
http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/docker.html

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER your name <your.user@example.org>

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y  software-properties-common
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv BC19DDBA
RUN add-apt-repository 'deb http://releases.galeracluster.com/ubuntu trusty main'

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y galera-3 galera-arbitrator-3 mysql-wsrep-5.6 rsync

COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
ENTRYPOINT ["mysqld"]
```

But I get this error

```
W: Failed to fetch http://releases.galeracluster.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Can you please help me !! It used to work fine for me two weeks ago !! any idea ??

Comment: It seams that the ubuntu folder was deleted from the server. If you access: http://releases.galeracluster.com you will see what is on the server, so you will need to look in their forum/support page to see if it is still available or not or if it was moved somewhere else

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://wiros4bleng.wordpress.com/2017/08/15/galera-cluster-with-mariadb-10-2-3-nodes-on-ubuntu-14-04-16-04-servers/ I'm not sure though

Comment: if you check releases.galeracluster.com/*anypath* you will see the ubuntu folder in all of them , and I want the releases.galeracluster packages not the umberterbuka.beritagar.id/mariadb one, thanks

Comment: So they moved the path. The error is very specific it is not able to find that specific path `http://releases.galeracluster.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages` So, somewhere in that repository, you will have to reconfigure the right path which is `http://releases.galeracluster.com/galera-3.22/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/` To know how to do that I think that AskUbuntu or ServerFault are the best places

Comment: Exactly !! I tagged them here, hopefully they will answer. thanks for your help

Comment: Well, if you don't want to wait, you can do it yourself: https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror

Answer (score 0):

please change your galera repository address.

here - > RUN add-apt-repository 'deb http://releases.galeracluster.com/ubuntu trusty main'

Open http://releases.galeracluster.com and make sure of the Galera version and distru

Choose the version and distribution you like and change it.